# One yield is working while other doesn't

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to yield header page as well as the content page. My routes are like this:

```
Route::get('projects/create', 'ProjectsController@create');
Route::get('/', function()
 {
    return view('pages.home');
 });
```

View>master.blade.php :

```
# Basic HTML stuff and <head></head>

<body>
    @yield('header')

    <div class="container text-center">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
</body>
```

Pages>View>Projects>Create.blade.php:

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')
  working
@stop
```

Pages>View>Pages>Header.blade.php:
    @extends('master')

```
@section('header')

 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="/pages/home">
         ...
 @if(Auth::user())
    ...
 @endif
 @stop
```

When I replace the whole header code with the @yield('header') section, it works perfectly. Do you have any clue?

Comment: I think you created `Create.php` file. But for using blade template elements you should create `Create.blade.php` file. Try to rename this file.

Comment: @LuckySaini sorry for the type, it's `create.blade.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have upgraded to laravel 5.1 ..you might want to try `@section- @endsection` for your blade template

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade